# react native calling a fat arrow function after setState: function is not defined

Tags: reactjs, native, setstate

On button pressed my App calls the handlePress function, which returns random objects from an array.

handlePress function:

```
handlePress = () => {
      this.setState({
        vitamin: getRandomIngredient(vitaminArray),
      }, ()=> matchMealPreference())
    }
```

If I replace matchMealPreference() with a console.log() it works just fine.

After setting the new states I want to call another function immediately with a fat arrow. Otherwise I run into async problems.

The matchMealPreference function looks like this:

```
matchMealPreference = () => {
      if(this.props.mealPreference === this.state.protein.getIngredientFlag()){
        return state
      } else {
        handlePress()
      }
    }
```

The function to get a random object from an array:

```
function getRandomIngredient (arr){
  if (arr && arr.length) {
    return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
  }
}
```

I get the error:

```
reference error. matchMealPreference is not defined
```

I'm almost certain that I'm missing something trivial. But I've been stuck at that problem for over a day now, so I thought I'd turn to you for help.

- Is there another way to call the matchMealPrefence without the asynchronous problems occuring?
- Is it at all possible to call a function at the position where matchMealPreference is called?
- Is it unwise to call the handlePress function within the matchMealPrefence function again?

Any help is much appreciated

Edit: Vijay Menon's answer was correct. I needed to add 'this'. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to reference "matchMealPreference" with "this" keyword inside setState. You would have to do the same for calling "handlePress" inside "matchMealPreference" function

https://codesandbox.io/s/542919430l

```
   changeStr = () => {
     this.setState({str:"Changed"})
   }
    click = () => {
      this.setState({num:this.state.num+1},() => {
        this.changeStr()
      })
    }
```